# Prove that $||u||\cdot ||v|| \geq |\langle u,v \rangle|$ for defined inner product

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $K$ be a totally complex number field such that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=n$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$ be its associated ring of integers. Let $\{\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n\}$ be the embeddings of $K$. For $u,v \in \mathcal{O}_K^2$, define the inner product:

$$
\langle u,v \rangle := \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i(u_1)\overline{\sigma_i(v_1)} + \sigma_i(u_2)\overline{\sigma_i(v_2)},
$$

where $u = (u_1,u_2)^T, v=(v_1,v_2)^T $ and $\bar{x}$ denotes complex conjugation. Define the norm of an element $u \in \mathcal{O}_K^2$ in the normal manner $||u|| = \langle u,u \rangle^{1/2}$. Is it possible to prove the following inequality:

$$
|\langle u,v \rangle| \leq ||u||\cdot ||v||,
$$

for all $u,v \in \mathcal{O}_K^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|\langle u,v\rangle|^2=\Big|\sum_i\sigma_i(u_1)\overline{\sigma_i(v_1)}+\sigma_i(u_2)\overline{\sigma_i(v_2)}\Big|^2\leqslant\Big( \sum_i|\sigma_i(u_1)||\overline{\sigma_i(v_1)}|+|\sigma_i(u_2)||\overline{\sigma_i(v_2)}|\Big)^2$$
From Cauchy-Schwartz we get
$$\Big( \sum_i|\sigma_i(u_1)||\overline{\sigma_i(v_1)}|+|\sigma_i(u_2)||\overline{\sigma_i(v_2)}|\Big)^2\\\leqslant\Big( \sum_i|\sigma_i(u_1)|^2+|\sigma_i(u_2)|^2\Big)^2\Big( \sum_i|\sigma_i(v_1)|^2+|\sigma_i(v_2)|^2\Big)^2\\=\Big( \sum_i\sigma_i(u_1)\overline{\sigma_i(u_1)}+\sigma_i(u_2)\overline{\sigma_i(u_2)}\Big)^2\Big( \sum_i\sigma_i(v_1)\overline{\sigma_i(v_1)}+\sigma_i(v_2)\overline{\sigma_i(v_2)}\Big)^2\\=||u||^2||v||^2$$

Comment: That was so simple, can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot!